# AngularJS calling a function from html element after an array is populated through ajax

Tags: angularjs, ajax

Firstly I should say that I'm new at angularjs

```html
<span grv-icon-comm-type="vm.communityViewHelper.getTypeIcon(vm.findFromPendingCommunityList(invite.community_id))" ng-class="vm.communityViewHelper.getColorClass(vm.findFromPendingCommunityList(invite.community_id))"></span>
```

In the above code `invite.community_id` is present with the page load. But `vm.findFromPendingCommunityList()` method is looping through an array which is populated by ajax response. In this situation when the function is called that array is empty but after a while array is populated by ajax call.

Now my question is how can I get the value there then?

Answer (score 0):

You could return a promise from your ajax call and when the promise gets resolved in the .then function you could assign the values to your array - once they are populated angularjs' built-in two-way data binding will do the job for you - iterating over the now populated array.

See: built-in services for achieving this task: $http, $q or $resource (check in documentation).

Easy way to test this is by using the built-in $timeout service (which uses promises internally) and to assign an array to the scope and then iterate over this array in the template. (you should include $timeout in your controller)

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
}, 5000)
```

Then in the template

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</ul>
```

You'll see that the array is iterated over after the 5 seconds delay from the $timeout. Hope that helps.